# vaadin 8 change URL

Tags: java, url, url-rewriting, vaadin, vaadin8

I'm using Vaadin 8 and I'm having some difficulty. I downloaded the project from this link [project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xejxaIQTO8) and modified it.

But I ran into a problem. You can go to the page of my project by following the link http://localhost:8080/app. But I am not satisfied with /app and would like to change this URL.

`@WebServlet settings(urlPatterns ="/*", name = "PrimeConfigurator", asyncSupported = true)`

I've already climbed a bunch of links and found nothing useful. Can you tell me which way to look and what to read to find a way to fix this problem?

I need to change the URL to the application with 
http://localhost:8080/app on http://localhost:8080/my_url_path

Comment: Does your project have a `context.xml` in the `META-INF` folder? If yes, then change it there, else you will need to modify it in your deployment to the tomcat server

Comment: Example code used in video doesn't override context root [WebConfig](https://github.com/alejandro-du/community-answers/blob/master/side-menu/src/main/java/com/example/WebConfig.java#L13), so app is deployed at `root`. Nor this example has "LoginView". Are you sure you are using exactly it?

Comment: I apologize for the link. I have a redirect applied to the login page and I did not notice when I inserted it in the example. The META-INF folder is empty. Just like the WEB-INF folder. Can I see more about the context.xml file somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean to deploy to production using a URL with `localhost:8080`? Or is this question referring only to running the web app from within your IDE?

Comment: Is this not just a case of adding a View to the Navigator with a View Name?

Comment: Actually, can you access your app using `localhost:8080`? Without any additional path? You have now mapping `.*`, it means that ALL matching paths will be redirected there. Try to add `\my_url_path` in `@WebServlet` `urlPatterns`, if you want discourage the use of `app`

Comment: This is the problem, the app is only available by link http://localhost:8080/app when you try to follow the link http://localhost:8080 I get a 404 error. This is strange. And therefore I have a question: how can I remove this most additional /app or change it to another value

Comment: We would need more info... Could you share your project on Github, for example? Or add all classes you have?